# How can I make list in a pandas dataframe by using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, list

This is Korean basketball player's stats in 2011.

[image: 1]

I need the list of players who have more than 55% of 2-point shot percentage.
So I made a code like this and it doesn't work

[image: 2]

it gives me this error

> ValueError from pandas\core\generic.py in *nonzero*(self)
>
> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Usse a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] to get started

Comment: `df[df['Average 2-point %'] > 55]`

Comment: Please avoid screenshots, copy paste few data in order to create a [mcve]

Comment: FYI, Jupyter notebook has no effect on the possible solutions here.

Comment: You've successfully loaded the `csv`.  Now you have a `pandas` Dataframe.  So it's no longer a `csv` topic - your title should reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new DataFrame using [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filepath')
df = df.loc[df['Average 2-point %'] > 55]]
```